# SharePoint Project Server deleting a project - REST

Tags: 2013, project-server

I am trying to find a way to delete a project using REST.

To fetch a project:
http://consoto.com/PWA/_api/ProjectData/Projects&$select=

To update a project:
http://contoso.com/PWA/_api/ProjectServer/Projects('projectid')/Draft/update()

Can't seem to find any documentation about the delete end point and how to use it.

Comment: Looks like this also may be of use: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj668384.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj669283.aspx might be what you're looking for.

`http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/ProjectServer/Projects('projectid')/deleteObject()`

Comment: Thanks, I was obviously not looking in the right place.

Comment: The documentation is a little scarce on Project Server programmability.